# How do I Forward Declare a Property in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, properties, forward-declaration

I have a class in C++/CLI that I'd like to give a property. I want to declare the property in a header file and then implement that property in a .cpp file.

Here's the header:

```
public ref class Dude
{
    static property Dude^ instance
    {
        Dude^ get();    
    }
}
```

If I declare the header file and don't put anything in the cpp, i get the following error:

```
1>Dude.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) Test.Dude::get_instance
```

From this I concluded that I should implement the property as

```
  static Lock myInstanceLock;

   Dude^ Dude::get_instance()
   {

       if(myInstance == nullptr)
       {
           myInstanceLock.lock();
           if(myInstance == nullptr)
           {
               myInstance = gcnew Dude();
           }
           myInstanceLock.unlock();             
       }
       return myInstance;
   }
```

However, when I compile this code, I get a bunch of errors. The first error (The others are a result of the first one) is:

```
1>.\Dude.cpp(13) : error C2039: 'get_instance' : is not a member of 'Test::Dude'
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the implementation to:

```
Dude^ Dude::instance::get()
```